# SFTP without password prompt (from linux to windows)

Tags: linux, windows, unix, sftp, ssh-keys

I'm using freeFTPd as a sftp server on windows machine. From my linux machine(ubuntu) I want to do a SFTP from to windows and i want to bypass entering password as i'm trying to do this with scripts. freeFTPd has an option to generate a key. I saw a lot of articles of key generation and but most of them are for linux to linux . Can some one please help me on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

ssh keys are the same kind of object on unix and windows - there are two types of keys: rsa, dsa.  Generally speaking rsa will work on either ssh 1 or ssh 2, so consider the key type of rsa if you are asked.

Generate the key, on linux with ssh-keygen:
http://rcsg-gsir.imsb-dsgi.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/documents/internet/node31.html

There will be two files created: public key, private key.   Make sure protections are 755 on (example home directory) `/home/m4n07`, and 600 on `/home/m4n07/.ssh`   after you have your key made.

The public key .ssh/id_rsa.pub  has to be placed on the Windows box. As a binary copy. Read the freeFTPd doc to find out where you place the file on your windows box, and what you name it.  Example: We have a non-standard sftp windows implementation that uses the registry for ssh keys.